# Swift - Run IBAction before unwinding from view controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, ibaction

So I have a "Save" button on a view controller, we'll call `VC2`. When clicked, it unwinds back the original view controller, we'll call `VC1`.

However, I want to run some logic on the data from `VC2` before I pass it back to `VC1`. I tried mapping an `IBAction` from the Save button that exits `VC2` and runs the unwind code on `VC1`. But I noticed it doesn't run the `IBAction` mapped to the button. I'm guess this is because it's linked to exit.

**So my question is:** if I have a button that exits my view controller, can I also have it linked to an `IBAction` so that I can run some logic on the view controller being exited (`VC2`) before it exists?

Comment: you using dismiss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your button is linked to a segue on the storyboard, its `IBAction`s does not seem to run. I don't know if this is documented anywhere, but that seems to be the behaviour.

Instead of linking the *button* to the "Exit" of `VC1`, link your `VC2` to the "Exit", then give that unwind segue an identifier, let's say `unwindToVC1`.

Now you can add your `IBAction` to the button, and write:

```
@IBAction func buttonPress() {
    // process your data or whatever

    // perform the unwind segue
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToVC1", sender: yourData)
}
```

Comment: So I think this will work great, but then it's not actually hitting the exit portion of the Segue, correct? So if I keep going back and forth it's going to allocate a bunch of VCs on the stack. I made a Segue from my VC2->VC1 and can call it in code, great. But every time I go back and forth now there's going to be another VC on the stack. Can I somehow associate this segue back to VC1 with an exit? (As far as I know that will pop it off the stack) I see some documentation online for popping VC on stack, I'll try it but very new to this.

Comment: @Birdman It _is_ an unwind segue. How did you link your unwind segue in the first place? You control+dragged from your button to the "Exit" of `VC1`, right? Instead of control+dragging from the button, control+drag from `VC2`. That will create an unwind segue, instead of a normal segue. And unwind segues will unwind, instead of presenting a new VC. `performSegue` can be used to perform both normal and unwind segues.

Comment: Basically, no new VCs will be pushed if you are using an unwind segue. @Birdman

Comment: Hi, I actually used a different method. I left it how I had it but I added a prepare for segue in my VC2, which gives me an opportunity to do the data manipulation I wanted to. However, I was unfamiliar with programatically performing a segue as you showed, so that was really helpful to me.